# ForceAutoLogon Ignored in windows 7 when setting up Autologin - Autologon

Tags: windows-7

I am attempting to setup automatic logon for a windows 7 kiosk computer via the registry.  I have set the values under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon like this:

```
AutoAdminLogon = 1
ForceAutoLogon = 1
DisableCAD = 1
```

I have filled out the username and password fields.
I have also deleted all EULA related values (a prerequisite of ForceAutoLogon)

I have done this procedure on 2 computers.

On computer A:
When rebooting, we logon automatically.
When logging out from the start menu, we logon automatically immediately after logging out.

On computer B:
When rebooting, we logon automatically.
When logging out from the start menu, we are presented with a logon menu where the user needs to click a user name & then enter a password.

It seems like the value of ForceAutoLogon requires some other prerequisite that is met on computer A, but not on computer B.

What do I need to make computer B act like computer A when clicking the log off button from the windows start menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A diff of the two registries using Regshot yielded the answer.  Machine B had a group policy set that runs a script on logoff which contained instructions to disable the AutoAdminLogon registry key.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the following values as well:
DefaultUsername
DefaultPassword
DeafultDomainName

Comment: Welcome to superuser, the question has been accepted, your answer maybe of use to the problem in general, but would need to be reworded to fit the question. Please have a read of these pages. http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou