# Why do I need to set up Autologon values in registry twice in before it works and can I fix this?

Tags: windows-7

Background: As part an automated testing suite I am building, I need to set up Autologon on my virtual machines 'on demand'. By on demand, I mean that I don't want to necessarily pre-configure my VM or any snapshot to have Autologon set up already, for security reasons and also a huge business case.

My solution so far: I'm copying a script to the guest machine and then using Sysinternals PsExec to execute it. The script is:

```
reg add "hklm\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d myusername
reg add "hklm\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d myfakepassword
reg add "hklm\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v DefaultDomainName /t REG_SZ /d mydomain
reg add "hklm\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v ForceAutoLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1
reg add "hklm\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /f /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1
reg add "hklm\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AutoLogonChecked" /f /ve /d 1
```

**Note**: I don't believe AutoLogonChecked is required for machines post Windows 2000 but I'm doing it just in case for now. Maybe ForceAutoLogon isn't either, not sure yet.

**The Problem**: I see PsExec executes this properly and all the values are in the registry, however when I restart the machine, the user isn't automatically logged on...When I run this a second time then restart the machine, the user is finally logged on.

A diff between the registry states shows that the first time I run this, it is missing both the "1" for AutoAdminLogon, and also the DefaultPassword key. The second time I execute it, these values are correctly intact as I intended.

So, what is going on here? Is this expected? [This](https://superuser.com/questions/487392/forceautologon-ignored-in-windows-7-when-setting-up-autologin-autologon) post claims in the end that it really all just works (the problem was that a logoff script was setting off the values). Doesn't seem to work for me however.

**Note this seems unique to Windows 7, does not occur in Windows XP**

Also note that you don't need PsExec to recreate the issue - just modify the registry yourself

***EDIT/update***:

- Login interactively and run script (so, not executing it remotely), logging off automatically logs me back in (so, it works)
- remotely execute the script in guest when I'm interactively logged in, logging off automatically logs me back in (so, it works)
- remotely execute the script in guest when with non-interactive session if I log in afterwards (so, interactive now) then back off, it logs me back in (so, it then works)

***EDIT/update 2***: This only occurs for Win7x86, Win7x64, Win8x64. **This does not occur for Windows XP**

***EDIT 3***: I get same behavior using Sysinsternal's Autlogon.exe tool.

Comment: After running your script once, What happens if you log off, log on, then reboot?

Comment: Can you see my edits above? Note that since I'm executing the script remotely "I" cannot necessarily log off. You have a good question, one that I'm not sure I'll be able to answer unless there's a utility where I can non-interactively log off and log on.

Comment: The plot thickens! hmmmm.

Comment: I'm really hoping for an answer here so I can sleep at night. I really think this would get the attention it needed if it were on Stack Overflow, may just keep entering dupes on SO until the Admin gives up and lets  it fly there

Comment: Did you tried it Run as Admin?

Comment: Sounds like the log off is doing something extra. Can you capture the complete registry before you start your script and compare it against the registry after you have logged in and then logged off?

Comment: @avirk I am executing it with PsExec with the Administrator token

Comment: @sgmoore - the complete registry?? There will surely be many differences, anything in particular I should be looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately you do need to check the complete registry. (If I knew what you were looking for, I would tell you). There has to be some difference between a working system and a non-working system and the difference obviously needs to be persisted across reboots, hence it is most likely to be stored in the registry.

Comment: I did do this once already but only specific to the Winlogon key. I'll do the whole thing and see what comes up of it and update my post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing login/password in registry in plain text isn't good idea...
I want to recommend you look at [LogonExpert](http://www.logonexpert.com) tool

Comment: I agree. Actually, the whole idea of Autologon isn't a 'good idea' either...Its meant for Kiosk situations where the system is locked down well from user's ability to do anything malicious. In other words, even if they can get to the clear text credentials, the credentials shouldn't take them very far. I've looked at logonexpert before. I believe there was a limitation, but I'll double check. Thanks!

Comment: +1 because this actually is the only tool that has worked for me / solved this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be something with PsExec.
Read this question and see if any of solutions there helps you:
[How do I change automatic logon via Script or Command Line?](https://superuser.com/questions/340396/how-do-i-change-automatic-logon-via-script-or-command-line)

Comment: I'll try the reg file approach I suppose. However note that this is not an issue for Winxp

Comment: reg file approach results in same behavior:  it is missing both the "1" for AutoAdminLogon, and also the DefaultPassword key. If I then logoff, execute the same reg file the same way, then log back in, it is intact as I intended

Comment: i was talking about the autologin tool...reg file is going to be same..moreover, try to avoid PsExec..something sounds fishy there...instead try windows startup scripts: http://serverfault.com/questions/57798/how-to-run-a-batch-script-before-the-windows-logon-prompt-appears

Comment: PsExec is not the culprit. Same behavior occurs with it taken out of the picture

Comment: PsExec merely runs the file as another user; basically the same as `runas` but with additional features (run as `SYSTEM`, run on remote computer). Manually logging in and running as any user would do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

tahocannan led me to LogonExpert. With LogonExpert, I can install it silently, set up Auto Logon with it, then (remotely) kill windows' LogonUI.exe process, then reboot. The result: automatically logged in. I then immediately uninstall LogonExpert, then execute commands interactively in the guest machine.

I believe killing the native-Windows "LogonUI.exe" process is the key here. Occasionally, I would get the same result with LogonExpert where after setting up Auto Logon, a reboot would not result in being logged in automatically as desired. By ending LogonUI.exe, it forces a re-load of LogonExpert's library. Then the reboot will work

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens because the first time you set AutoAdminLogon = 1 there is also another registry value in Windows 7 called AutoLogonCount which is set to 0. If Windows sees this value set to 0 in the registry when it boots up it will disable AutoAdminLogon and this is why when you reboot you are not able to auto logon. If you delete AutoLogonCount from the registry at the same time you set your AutoAdminLogon to 1, then you should be ok after reboot.

While the idea of autologon is understood to be unsafe for regular desktop use, autoLogon is very useful for special computers, such as kiosks or computers attached to a demo display or monitoring devices where software needs to load automatically after booting up.