# Script to enable autologon for users on a domain won't work unless I run it twice

Tags: batch, windows-registry, autologon

So I'm having an issue with a script that enables autologon domain users. For some reason I have to run it twice for the option to be enabled on the computer.

The Script:

```
@echo off
REM Set variables
set /p user-name= What is the username?
set /p domain= What is the domain name?
set /p password= What is the password?

REM Enable Auto Logon
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1

REM Set Username for logon
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d %user-name%

REM Set Domain
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultDomainName /t REG_SZ /d %domain%

REM Set Password
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d %password%
```

I tried to use [this program](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963905.aspx) from the Technet and I had the same issue with it too.

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: similar: http://superuser.com/questions/487395/why-do-i-need-to-set-up-autologon-values-in-registry-twice-in-before-it-works-an

Answer (score 0):

I switched to PowerShell using this script:

```
$TheUser = Read-Host "What is the username?"
$ThePassword = Read-Host "What is the password?" -AsSecureString
$TheDomain = Read-Host "What is the domain?"
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name AutoAdminLogon -Value 1
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name DefaultUserName -Value "$TheUser"
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name DefaultPassword -Value $ThePassword
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name DefautDomainName -value $TheDomain
```

But each time I execute the script I get this error message:

> New-ItemProperty : The property already exists At
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Autologon.ps1:4 char:17 +
>   New-ItemProperty <<<< -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name AutoAdminLogon -Value 1 +
>   CategoryInfo : ResourceExists:
>   (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...ersion\Winlogon:String) [New-ItemProperty],
>   IOException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemPropertyCommand
>   New-ItemProperty : The property already exists At
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Autologon.ps1:5 char:17 +
>   New-ItemProperty <<<< -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name DefaultUserName -Value "$TheUser" +
>   CategoryInfo : ResourceExists:
>   (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...ersion\Winlogon:String) [New-ItemProperty],
>   IOException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemPropertyCommand
>   New-ItemProperty : The property already exists At
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Autologon.ps1:6 char:17 +
>   New-ItemProperty <<<< -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name DefaultPassword -Value $ThePassword
>   + CategoryInfo : ResourceExists: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...ersion\Winlog on:String) [New-ItemProperty], IOException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemPropertyCommand
>   New-ItemProperty : The property already exists At
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Autologon.ps1:7 char:17 +
>   New-ItemProperty <<<< -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name DefautDomainName -value $TheDomain +
>   CategoryInfo : ResourceExists:
>   (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...ersion\Winlogon:String) [New-ItemProperty],
>   IOException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemPropertyCommand

Not sure how I can fix this and I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the key already exist, you need to use -Force in order to overwrite it. You can add it at the end

```
    $TheUser = Read-Host "What is the username?"
    $ThePassword = Read-Host "What is the password?" -AsSecureString
    $TheDomain = Read-Host "What is the domain?"
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name AutoAdminLogon -Value 1 -Force
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name DefaultUserName -Value "$TheUser" -Force
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name DefaultPassword -Value $ThePassword -Force
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon' -Name DefautDomainName -value $TheDomain -Force
```

Comment: How is your answer consistent with the OP’s statement that the script works the second time it is run?

Comment: Its consistent with the latest post. I dont know why you have to run that batch script twice, but I know why powershell gave him an error.